# css separator of two float divs

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/dx6m9/

```
    <style>
    .floated {float: left;}
    .container {width: 100%;}
    .left, .right {
        width:60%; 
        box-sizing:border-box; 
        padding:10px;
}
    .left {width:40%; border-right: 1px dotted #dddddd;}
    .clearfix {clear:both;}
    </style>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="floated left">
          Ahoj
        </div>
        <div class="floated right">
            Nazdar
            <br />
            Ahoj
            <br />
             Nazdar
            <br />
            Ahoj

        </div>
     <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
```

how to force the right border to be always long as longer of these two float divs?
That border should acts just like a separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by adding a 3rd seperator div [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6m9/3/) and set this to 40% left.

```
.sep {
    position: absolute;
    left:40%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-left: 1px dotted #ddd;
}
.container {
    width: 100%; 
    position:relative
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
.floated {display:table-cell;}
.container {width: 100%;display:table}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6m9/2/)

Comment: This will work, but clearfix div should be taken out of the container div (or removed entirely), since it will get stuck to the far-right as another cell of the container div. Also, any further content should also be taken out of the container div if it is to be displayed under this two-column content.

Answer (score 2):

This is only achievable with either tables (either in markup as a `<table>` or using `table-cell` in CSS) or using a background-image, as described in [Faux Columns](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns).

This question, in one form or another, has been asked a lot on this site. Try searching 'equal height columns' in [css](/questions/tagged/css) and you will find quite a few similar responses.

Answer (score 0):

here you find exactly what you want:  http://jsfiddle.net/stryd3r/dx6m9/5/

Is made with a simple Jquery function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight=$( '.left' ).height();
    if  ($( '.right' ).height()>maxHeight)
        maxHeight=$( '.right' ).height();
    $( '.dotted' ).css('height',maxHeight);
});
```